# swf fails to fill window when height is set to 100%

Tags: javascript, html, actionscript-3, flash

I am having the hardest time. I am trying to make a flash recorder that runs behinds the scenes and is controlled via JavaScript. When we flash need permission I want to have flash fill the browser window but when ever i set the height or width property to 100% my swf vanishes entirely where am i going wrong?

```
<div id="flashrecorder">
   <object wmode="transparent" 
           id="recoderObject" 
           data="/artwork/html5/recoder.swf" 
           allowscriptaccess="always" 
           type="application/x-shockwave-flash" 
           loop="false" 
           name="flashrecorder" 
           height="100%" 
           width="100%">
       <param name="FlashVars" value="webpath=https://test.com">
    </object>
</div>
```

if flash has a set value for height & width like 300 it works

update-> So I found that I can set width to 100% but using height causes it to vanish

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding the parameter **scale**.

```
<param name="scale" value="exactfit">
```